# android smooth animation while running heavy code (theoretical)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-animation

I have a view with a `ProgressBar` on it that just sits and spins (smoothly).

Meanwhile I'm doing a network load via `AsyncTask`. When the load is done, I'm processing all the `JSON` data into a visual layout which takes about 1.5 seconds to do. However, during that 1.5 seconds my `ProgressBar` animation comes to a complete halt.

How can I make it so I can process the data, but keep my animation smooth as well?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code by which you are processing the layout.

Comment: @MrZander This is a theoretical question because I know I'll run into this problem, so there's no code just yet. I'm seeking help for the idea first before I get myself into a mess :/  --  I *apologize* for any confusion.

Comment: Blocking the UI thread for 1.5 seconds is something you will never want to do. I cannot think of any reasonable explanation why you would ever allow that. Their is always a better way, that is why Google created StrictMode.

Comment: If you're doing all the non-UI work in AsyncTask, your ProgressBar will be smooth.  It's running on a separate thread.  I think that's the confusion here because this is precisely what AsyncTask was designed for.

Comment: @DeeV for the loading of the data you are absolutely correct. However, the data is passed back to the main thread which processes the data into visual layouts (that's where the stress is). Are you suggesting I try processing the visual data in the async as well?

Comment: @HandlerExploit StrictMode is for javascript (I use it all the time). This is for Java/Android. If there's a StrictMode for Java, I'm more than happy to take a look at it!

Comment: @Jackson Yeah, or some kind of threading system.  AsyncTask is essentially a thread wrapper that allows you to periodically pass data to the UI thread when it becomes available.  It doesn't have to be limited to blocking operations.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is difficult to assess without code to work with, I will give it a shot.

You could simply process the JSON and create your `View` inside the `AsyncTask` and then pass the `View` back to the GUI thread in `onPostExecute`.

This way no heavy calculations are being done on the GUI thread.